# Faster JSON deserialization with huge int JSON array

Tags: android, json, gson, moshi

I have to deserialize a Json object in Android with a huge Int Json array inside.

The schema is like:

```
{ 
   "key1": "value1",
   "key2": "value2",
   "smallObject": {
      "key": "value"
   },
   "smallArray" [
      {}, {} ,{}
   ],
   "hugeObject": {
      "data": {
          "hugeIntArray": [
              -1, -1, 1, 2, -1 ...
          ]
      },
      "key": "value"
   }
}
```

The length of `hugeIntArray` array can be over 2,000,000, and making JSON file larger than 15 MB.

I tried to parse with Gson, which will take 7 seconds, also Moshi, which will take 11 seconds.

I found Moshi can do lazy loading with customize JsonAdapter and sequence. But I can't apply it to my schema.

My target is to use it like a sequence or stream to convert the int values into pixels of a image.

Comment: There won't a good answer since you're using a wrong tool. Don't use binary data serialization/deserialization like that: it wastes both traffic and resources. I guess you need a byte array (I guess your int array won't have non-byte values) at least. It would be very nice to know the length of the byte array in advance, by prepending something like hugeIntArrayLength/hugeByteArrayLength to reduce number of intermediate array allocations (how can Gson or Moshi know the final length in advance otherwise?).

Comment: Packing binary data in a JSON is mostly a bad idea with more reasons of not doing so. Even encoding it to a Base64-encoded string as suggested below is a bad idea: reading huge strings will stress your devices anyway suffering from intermediate objects allocation. Another thing is that, if you're using a web socket, the WS consumer should only consume messages (probably as fast as possibly: huge arrays are out of that suggestion).

Comment: The best choice here is completely refusing the idea of sending binary data like that in JSON, but put resource URLs that refer the binary data instead of huge arrays, and only load such resources when if it's really necessary. As result: your app will use less memory, it will work faster from Gson/Moshi point of view, it will load linked resources on demand (probably in optimized way), and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any way you can avoid using Json in this case? The data should really be in a binary format

Comment: Thanks for the advice. 

There is a websocket kept sending messages to Android through the callback

`fun onMessage(conn: WebSocket, message: String)`

Under current convention, message has the schema of JSON, so I can parse the its message type/uri and the reset payload to do further things.

Comment: What about replaciing `hugeIntArray` with a base64-string which contains a binary representation of the array? This is especially useful if every int is known to be a small number. If so, you can squeeze several of them into one byte. It would still be Json

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. I compressed the `hugeIntArray`, with Base64 -> Gzip -> Base64, now it is a string with 10% length, and the JSON file reduced from 15 MB to 0.6 MB, the parsing speed is just milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [JsonReader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader)? It's specifically made to read json files as a stream

Comment: Yes. As I see from Moshi, it ues JsonAdapter with `moshi` JsonReader to parse any JSON.

If I use default Moshi setup, it generates an adapter like the following to parse this field.

`hugeIntArray = listOfIntAdapter.fromJson(reader) ?: throw Util.unexpectedNull("hugeIntArray", "hugeIntArray", reader)`

It ends up quite slow. I thought it might be similar with Android JsonReader.